# Dynamically add javascript slideshow code to header of templated site

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash

I am working with a very outdated templated site that does not let me change anything in the top portion of the site. The Flash slideshow no longer works properly, so I was wondering if there was any way Javascript/JQuery can be added to the accessable part of the site that will dynamically replace the existing flash slideshow with a Javascript slideshow I have made?

The site is: http://www.familymattersteam.com/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: existing script isn't in the head. It's in the content section. Just swap it out with what you want to use

Comment: I apologize. I meant "header" in the "top of the page" sense, and not in the html sense. I will update the post accordingly. 

That being said, I am still unable to access that portion of the page. I can only access things below the navigational menu.

Comment: one script is below the menu in the content area. You can use jQuery `remove()` method to remove the container(s) with flash in them. May or may not cause the flash scripts to throw errors

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way to add any in-line Javascript/JQuery to the "SlideShow" ID once I remove it though? 

As a last resort I am thinking about adding the following code to replace the slideshow with an image:

picture = document.getElementById('SlideShow'); 
picture.innerHTML = '<img src="image link" width="874" height="206">'; 

However, I would prefer to replace the broken slideshow with a working one if at all possible. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the following code to the "script footer" portion of the site's back end. I just started learning Javascript about a week ago, and I borrowed this code from another out of date site, so I'm sure its painful to look at. It works though!

Essentially all I did was used the innHTML command to replace the contents in the "SlideShow" ID with code for a Javascript slideshow.

```
var t;
var slideShowSpeed = 5000;
var crossFadeDuration = 2;

var PicA = new Array();

PicA[0] = '/Repository/1/4/1/0/7/9/141079/template_files/slide1.jpg';
PicA[01] = '/Repository/1/4/1/0/7/9/141079/template_files/slide2.jpg';
PicA[02] = '/Repository/1/4/1/0/7/9/141079/template_files/slide3.jpg';
PicA[03] = '/Repository/1/4/1/0/7/9/141079/template_files/slide4.jpg';
PicA[04] = '/Repository/1/4/1/0/7/9/141079/template_files/slide5.jpg';

var j = 0;
var p = PicA.length; 
var preLoadA = new Array();

for (i = 0; i < p; i++) {
preLoadA[i] = new Image();
preLoadA[i].src = PicA[i];
};

function runSlideShowA() {

if (document.all) {
document.images.SlideShowA.style.filter='blendTrans(duration=2)';
document.images.SlideShowA.style.filter='blendTrans(duration=crossFadeDuration)';
document.images.SlideShowA.filters.blendTrans.Apply();
};

document.images.SlideShowA.src = preLoadA[j].src;

if (document.all) {
document.images.SlideShowA.filters.blendTrans.Play();
};

j = j + 1;
if (j > (p - 1)) j = 0;
t = setTimeout('runSlideShowA()', slideShowSpeed);
};

newSlide = document.getElementById('SlideShow'); 
newSlide.innerHTML = '<img src="/Repository/1/4/1/0/7/9/141079/template_files/slide1.jpg" name="SlideShowA" width="874" height="206">';

runSlideShowA();
```